# Как по клику на строку в Datagrid открыть новое окно и передать туда выделенную строку

Tags: c#, wpf

Все происходит в WPF, нужно не нарушить паттерн MVVM. В DAtaGrid вывелись данные, при клике выделяется строка, я эту строку получаю свойством прибинденным во View в виде object. Как сделать функцию, чтобы при двойном клике на строку в датагрид, открывалось новое окно и в нем отобразил бы содержимое этой строки.
Смущает меня то, что  если я делаю событие во view типа MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" тогда создается обработчик во view и там я могу открыть это окно, но верно ли это будет с точки зрения паттерна, ибо мне нужно будет забирать данные о выбранной строке из ViewModel.

Comment: Можно использовать Behaviors. Если коротко, то пишете класс, в нём описываете поведение для определённого события, в вашем случае DoubleClick, и вешаете этот behavior нужному контролу

Comment: @dmepty да я так и думал, что нужно писать свой обработчик события, но как его приделать во view не знаю, а подскажите как со Behaviors. работать на простом примере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью `Behaviors`.

Покажу на примере с событие закрытия окна. Суть не меняется для других контролов.

Сперва нам нужно добавить ссылку на сборку `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

Затем мы создаём сам `Behavior`.

```
class ClosingBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Closing += AssociatedObjectOnClosing;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
    {
        //Логика закрытия
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.Closing -= AssociatedObjectOnClosing;
    }
}
```

Этот класс должен наследоваться от `Behavior`. Генерик типом указываем нужный нам контрол. Например для `TextBox'a` Это будет `Behavior<TextBox>`.

Затем в разметке мы добавляем:

`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

И привязываем к нужному нам контролу этот `Behavior`.

```
<Window 
    ...
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    ...>

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <smartHouse:ClosingBehavior/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>

...

</Window>
```

Comment: я логику понял, почти, но все таки а как мне привязаться к контролу нужному, в моем случае это датагрид и привязать это Поведение, то есть у меня при двойном клике возникает событие, как мне к нему привязать это поведение.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Наследуетесь от Behavior<DataGrid>, потом в AssociatedObject подписываетесь на событие DoubleClick

Comment: Так уже понятнее, а само окно мне где генерить получается туже в AssociatedObject или как? Если я тут подпишусь на событие, то обработка этого события где реализуется?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch По сути, вам надо генерить окно в методе, подписанном на событие, например AssociatedObjectDoubleClick. Обработка происходит в этом же методе

Comment: а в xaml как мне прицепиться к событию?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Через <i:Interaction.Behaviors>. Я все расписал в ответе. Если недостаточно информации, её всегда можно найти в гугле